# How do I know if a transaction is legit?

Tags: fraud, lost-transactions

A sender confirmed by email that he sent out bitcoins and even provided a link to the transaction on blockchain. I was never able to find it on blockchain. Just like it doesn't even exist. I talked to him and he told me it was suspended by miners.
I don't know much about this but this just sounds like a huge scam.

Can anybody help me please? Thanks

Blockchain was: 5a48441b1c47812d3a2ba01f30316c2ec6ee8969634ff304650560689a7cf3a3

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked on three different blockexplorers, and none of them knew about this transaction. Your sender may have tried to pay you, but they definitely didn't succeed, so it's up to them to remedy that.

You know that a transaction is legit when it was confirmed in a block and the money has actually been transferred to you. Before the transaction is confirmed, it's merely a payment promise.

Comment: Thank you Murch. The provider used to send transaction numbers by email and they always went through. So when I received this one...I thought all good.
I guess he just invented transaction to have an excuse. His excuse in this case..."miners stopped transaction" and "its not in his hands anymore".

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Transaction ID.

Then you can put the Transaction ID into any of many different BlockChain tools.

BlockChain.Info is one popular one.

Here is one recent transaction for about $400 in BTC.

https://blockchain.info/tx/9c5dadf369e8a7779db1bcd8cc54b00e39136c7bcddcd17a93c7d8a87658e343

## The number you provided does not look to be valid as a transaction ID.

Comment: https://blockchain.info/tx/5a48441b1c47812d3a2ba01f30316c2ec6ee8969634ff304650560689a7cf3a3

but it says it doesnt exist

Comment: That is what I said: **"The number you provided does not look to be valid as a transaction ID"**.   (I just put it in big bold letters, so you won't miss it this time)

Comment: Could you kindly explain WHY IT DOESN´T LOOK like a valid transaction ID. Or did you just take that info from searching for the blockchain. Both have just numbers and left handed keyboard letters. 

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: It is not a valid transaction ID because it does not appear on BlockChain tools.   (no, you cannot tell if it is valid just by eyeballing it).   Until your sender can provide you with a valid Transaction ID, that shows up in major tools, shows your wallet as the recipient and has at least 3 to 6 "confirmations", you have not actually received any Bitcoin.  It does not mean its a "scam", it just means he has not paid you yet.

Comment: so once a real batch is created...is there anyway that it can be suspended, stopped, canceled or maybe returned?

Comment: You are using terminology that makes no sense at all in Bitcoins:  there is no such thing as a "real batch", and one user cannot "provide a blockchain".   If you're going to ask questions, you need to learn enough terminology to ask a coherent question.